# Pandas: Compare value for a column by each row between 2 dataframes and replace value in another column based on the match

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

DF1:

```
    SICCode Industry Title
0   4941    AGRICULTURAL PRODUCTION-CROPS
1   7374    AGRICULTURAL PROD-LIVESTOCK & ANIMAL SPECIALTIES
2   5065    AGRICULTURAL SERVICES
3   4941    FORESTRY
4   5122    FISHING, HUNTING AND TRAPPING
```

DF2:

```
    SICCode Sector
0   4941    Buseq
1   7374    utils
2   5065    shops
3   4941    utils
4   5122    Buseq
```

DF1 is the master; I want to check for each SIC Code in DF1 in SIC Code in DF2 and if it is there, I want to replace the value in Sector column by the corresponding value under Industry Title. For e.g., for 4941 in DF1, it should against all values in SIC Code in DF2 and replace Buseq and utils with "Agricultural Production crops".

I tried .map, .isin, if-else, etc. but not able to move forward. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Quick question, DF1 has 4941 twice. Since you said it's master data, wanted to check whether it's a typo?

Comment: I was able to do a inner join merge, but it reduced the dataset by around 100 rows. The dataset for analysis has 7805 rows and I do not want to change that dimension.

Comment: @incrediblegiant Yes, that is a typo. Correct. Since it is master, there should be a single instance of that code. In DF2, the industry title value corresponding to 4941 in DF1 should be updated everywhere where 4941 shows up.

Answer (score 0):

BE CAREFUL, in your master df SICCode is not a primary key, in the example your show there is two rows with the same code which could be a problem, be aware of that (I have arbitrary edited the SICCode of Forestry in the solution but if you don't Buseq and utils would be replaced by Forestry)

I see 2 solution to your issue:

- Using only pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = {'SICCode':[4941,7374,5065,4944,5122], \
       'Industry_Title' :['AGRICULTURAL PRODUCTION-CROPS',\
                          'AGRICULTURAL PROD-LIVESTOCK & ANIMAL SPECIALTIES',\
                          'AGRICULTURAL SERVICES','FORESTRY',\
                          'FISHING  HUNTING AND TRAPPING']}
df2 =  {  'SICCode':[4941,7374,5065,4941,5122], 'Sector': ['Buseq','utils','shops','utils','Buseq']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

for index in df2.index:

    to_replace = df1[df1['SICCode'] == df2.loc[index,'SICCode']]
    for i in to_replace['Industry_Title'].index:
        df2.loc[index,'Sector'] = to_replace['Industry_Title'][i]
```

- Using sqlite3:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sql

df1 = {'SICCode':[4941,7374,5065,4944,5122], \
       'Industry_Title' :['AGRICULTURAL PRODUCTION-CROPS',\
                          'AGRICULTURAL PROD-LIVESTOCK & ANIMAL SPECIALTIES',\
                          'AGRICULTURAL SERVICES','FORESTRY',\
                          'FISHING  HUNTING AND TRAPPING']}
df2 =  {  'SICCode':[4941,7374,5065,4941,5122], 'Sector': ['Buseq','utils','shops','utils','Buseq']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)  

conn = sql.connect('test_database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS df1 (SICCode Integer, Industry_Title Text)')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS df2 (SICCode Integer, Sector Text)')


df1.to_sql('df1', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)
df2.to_sql('df2', conn, if_exists='replace', index = False)
# create the database witht the table

to_replace = c.execute("""
          Select df2.SICCode,Industry_Title From
          df1 Join df2 On df1.SICCode=df2.SICCode
          """).fetchall()
# select rows with same SICCode in df1 and df2

for x in to_replace:
    c.execute("""
              Update df2 Set Sector = '{}'
              Where SICCode = {}
              """.format(x[1],x[0]))
    #updates the row of df2

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this works...and you are right - the SIC Code in the master data should not have been repeated - it was a typo.

Comment: How does the above solution (pandas version) work if the master data had a range to check for? Meaning, if I had to check for a code 4723 to exist between 0100-3000 and then do the same subsequent activity (change sector value)? I am trying the isin method, but it throws an error on index.

Comment: @risky2109
you can do it by adding a condition on your SICCode,

for example    if 100<df2.loc[index,'SICCode']<3000:
I'm not sure  if it was what you were willing to do, the meaning of exist for a number is a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit crude, but works.

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on="SICode", how="left")
df2.drop(['Sector'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did the same but it reduced the dataset for me (reduced by almost 90 rows). Will check again on this...I may have done something wrong...thanks again!

Comment: Since the join is by "left", it will remove rows if there is no matching master record in df1. You can use "outer" to handle NaNs.